# How to find a description of a function/interface/etc

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

The following is possibly two questions.
When trying to avoid asking questions here at Stackoverflow I guess each and everyone of us do the following:
searches need to consider a number of questions to grade an answers relevance to the personal experience of:

- the language used (C#),
- the area of interest (WEB/REST),
- the development environment (Visual Studio),
- the used framework (dotNET/Servicestack/Database),
- current versions of the used parts (C#, dotNET/Servicestack, Database, etc),
- experience of the previous fields (recent),
- experience of programming (long),
- the age of the found answers (gives latest possible version of included parts [C#,dotNET,...]) which in turn gives an inkling of the answers relevance to the original question. Well, unless the question is recent, asking about an old version of some program.

I stumbled on an interface in Servicestack *IhasId*
If I (in VisualStudio) check it's definition I get the following:

```
namespace ServiceStack.Model
{
    public interface IHasId<T>
    {
        T Id { get; }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to figure out it's use and when it's needed ?
I thought Servicestack/Ormlite figured out the key by looking at the name (Id).

```
public class TheUser : IHasId<int> // Why is the interface needed here?
{
    [ServiceStack.DataAnnotations.AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Is *IHasId* old and not needed anymore or is it just needed in some cases to  disambiguate some situation ?
I guess this interface is used by the framework (Servicestack).
I am sure I'll have more questions like this one, later on.

Answer (score 2):

Normally in visual studio you can simply right click on the interface name and select "Find usage". If it returns zero results, comment out the code and build. If it builds. It isn't used, and can safely be deleted. Unless something extremely weird is going on.

Comment: Thanks @Morten Bork, I'll try that.
In this case its not that simple I am not shure if this is used by the framework (Servicestack) to help creating a database-model, code first.

Comment: The key here is that this is a 3rd party name space `namespace ServiceStack.Model`, so you can't remove the interface itself,only if your class implements it.  In this case you'd want to remove the interface reference, then go through some runtime testing that definitely would use that object by `Id`, or in this specific case, generate a database from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

The `IHasId<T>` interface is never needed in ServiceStack itself, it's useful for your own code if you want to enforce a specific Id type or if you want a generic routine be able to handle your data models with a specific Id type, e.g:

```
if (model is IHasId<string> hasStringId) {
    string id = hasStringId.Id;
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mythz. Can I find this in the Servicestack documentation or is this something I should know by glance at the code ?

Comment: @EnTermosJava No, it’s just a marker interface which lets you access the Id property of models using typed c#.